# Every component of $C_{\infty}-K$ contains a component of $C_{\infty}-G$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

The following is a question from Conway on the section of Runge's theorem:

> Let $K$ be a compact subset of the open set $G \subset \mathbf{C}$ and suppose all bounded components $D$ of $G-K$ satisfy $\overline{D}\cap \partial G \neq \emptyset$. Then every component of $C_{\infty}-K$ contains a component of $C_{\infty}-G$.

Attempt: Let $H$ be any component of $C_{\infty}-K$.

If $H$ is the unbounded component and $H'$ is the unbounded component of $C_{\infty}-G$ then as $\infty \in H \cap H'$, we must have $H' \subset H$ by the following facts:

1. If $A,B \subset X$ and are both connected with $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$ then $A\cup B$ is connected
2. Components are the largest connected sets.

If $H$ is bounded, it suffices to show $H \cap (C_{\infty}-G) \neq \emptyset$, since then, if $z$ is in the intersection and $H'$ is the component of $C_{\infty}-G$ containing $z$, then by the same logic as above, $H' \subset H$.

So, suppose $H \cap (C_{\infty}-G) = \phi$. Then as $H$ is bounded this means $H \cap (C-G)= \emptyset$, i.e. $H \subset G$. I am not sure how to proceed from here. How should I use the given information about components of $G-K$?